# Why does the table title does not follow directly after the table number?

Tags: tables, captions

As shown below, my table title does not follow directly after its number, it starts from another line. I need your help to figure out why this happens. How I can fix this problem?

[image]

My code is as follows:

```
\documentclass[tech,thesis,apacite,nochapterblankpages,uglyheadings]{puthesis-cot}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
\caption {Square Test Result}
\begin{tabular}{llllll}
Index & Time & FileName & size & Num   & Yes/No \\ 
3, 4 & 1 & Red\_tif\_16\_100w100h.tif & 100*100 & 10000 & Yes \\ 
\end{tabular} 
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)  How to know without knowing that document class and packages are you using? Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: I use the template from our website https://engineering.purdue.edu/~mark/puthesis/ It uses \documentclass[tech,thesis,apacite,nochapterblankpages,uglyheadings]{puthesis-cot} \usepackage{indentfirst} \newcommand{\ip}{\mbox{}\indent} \usepackage{fixltx2e} ... But I did not find any packages that is for tables. Does this explanation make sense?

Comment: I am sorry that I am totally fresh for the Latex, please tell me what I need to describe to let you answer the question easily.

Comment: I suddenly find when I use this code in my document, I find my title under the table.\usepackage{float}
\restylefloat{table}
\usepackage{placeins}

Comment: Thank you for your comments, I have solved the table position problem through the following code:\documentclass[12pt]{article} \usepackage{float}
\floatstyle{plaintop}
\restylefloat{table}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[t]
\caption{Four months plan: where,what how}
\begin{tabular}{lclclclc}
\hline
\hline
Month & Week & Programme\\
\hline
May & 3-4 & Cycle Tour\\
June & 1-2 & DCP Project\\
July & 1-2 & Clean Energy\\
August & 3-4 & Interim Report\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}

Comment: That code actually probably won't work if your documentclass is `puthesis-cot`; see the answer below.

Comment: Are you writing a thesis or an article? The `article` class do not allow some commands of non standard thesis templates or even the very standard book class, like `\chapter{}`, so switch to the `article` class for the format of the captions is a very bad idea (except if you want to make an article instead of a thesis).

Comment: You may be using an obsolete or otherwise substandard version of the file `puthesis-cot.cls`. The version that may be obtained from the github repository -- see https://github.com/jrstjohn/puthesis-cot -- was updated just a few months ago, and it doesn't exhibit the problem behavior you've encountered. More specifically, the updated code places the table's caption *centered and below* the table number, rather than flush-right.

Answer (score 2):

Now that we know what class you're using, we can see that putting the caption on the next line after the tablename and number is part of your class file.  You can confirm this by running the MWE I've edited into your question.  `puthesis-cot.cls` dictates this behavior in a rather long and complex `\@makecaption` definition.

Changing this probably a bad idea, since this is the class you're supposed to be using for your thesis.  However, if you must, the operative lines are 1317--1362 in `puthesis-cot.cls`; it a complex definition, but for your particular use case, I think what you're looking for is 1335--1342.  Change what it is now to the following:

```
          \centerline{#1:  #2}
%          \sbox\@tempboxa{#2}%
%          \ifdim \wd\@tempboxa >\hsize
%            \centerline{\parbox[t]{\@@captionwidth}{#2}}
%          \else
%            \centerline{#2}%
%          \fi
        }
```

That way the solution will work with your documentclass.  You may need to fiddle with the other conditional branches in the definition for other figures and tables in your document; this only works with the MWE in the question.  I don't have the time to sort through the various branchings, so I only made it work in this one case.

By the way:  the `puthesis-cot.cls` wasn't available at the site you linked; I had to Google it to find it.  It's kind to link to a non-standard document class in your question in the future.

Comment: You're welcome; but on TeX.SE, we don't usually post thanks; upvotes and accepted answers are the preferred form of thanks here.  Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: The proposed remedy -- `\centerline{#1:  #2}` -- fails badly if the combined width of table title, number, and text exceeds the width of the text block.

Comment: Good point; but that's a problem with the class file already.  And loading `caption` (something I would think the class designer probably should have done anyway) could override other behavior in the class.  It's probably safer to change as little as possible of the class file.

Answer (score 2):

(Too long for a comment, hence posted as an answer.)

I suspect the problem you report -- the fact that the first part of the table caption is centered, whereas the second part is set at the far-left of the next row, after a line break -- may be due to you using an obsolete or otherwise substandard version of the document class file `puthesis-cot.cls` ("Purdue University College of Techology").

For sure, if I use the version of the class file that's available on the relevant [github site](https://github.com/jrstjohn/puthesis-cot), I get the following look for the table shown in your MWE:

[image]

Note that the second part of the caption is *centered* rather than set flush-left. The date associated with the class file downloaded from github is Dec 2014, i.e., quite recent.

If you do *not* want a line break between "Table 1" and "Square Test Result", I think the easiest way to proceed would be to load the `caption` package in the preamble.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tech,thesis,apacite,nochapterblankpages,uglyheadings]{puthesis-cot}
\usepackage{caption} % re-format captions
\usepackage{url}     % for "\path" macro
\usepackage{booktabs}% for \toprule, \midrule, and \bottomrule
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
\caption {Square Test Result}
\begin{tabular}{@{}llllll@{}}
\toprule
Index & Time & FileName & size & Num   & Yes/No \\ 
\midrule
3, 4 & 1 & \path{Red_tif_16_100w100h.tif} & 100*100 & 10000 & Yes \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabular} 
\end{table}
\end{document}
```